# Adding in SQL from Timestamp adding time

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, datetime

I am trying to store date and time in UTC in sql but it is getting stored as something else only.

In react, I am using local date time in my input to send the request body to the API.

The API is simple, getting the date and storing it in sql.
But it is adding time rather than subtracting from it.
I am in IST Timezone.
the requestbody :

```
{"date" : "2022-09-08 12:30"}
```

In the database, it is storing as 2022-09-08 18:00 whereas it should store 2022-09-08 07:00.
The java API:

```
exampleFunction(Timestamp date) {
// store in db;
// return success or failure
}
```

I am not able to understand what is happening and also was not able to find any way after trying.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Then you can also explicitly specify that it is in UTC.

Comment: You are giving us very little to work with. What is the data type in SQL? Which brand of database engine are you using? A [mre], please?